# How to fix hang of sctp_sendmsg to unreachable host

Tags: c, linux-kernel, sctp

I am using Linux SCTP via lksctp-tools (CentOS 7.3, lksctp-tools-1.0.17-2.el7.x86_64) in my C application. How to avoid hang of `sctp_sendmsg()` function when it is used to establish a new SCTP association with the unreachable destination host.

When `sctp_sendmsg()` is triggered from C code to establish new SCTP association with dest host which is not reachable then it hangs for several minutes and in wireshark, I see that Linux sends SCTP INIT retries. 
How to avoid this hang? 
Is it possible to configure some timeout (for ex: 1 sec) which will interrupt `sctp_sendmsg()` or is it possible somehow quickly check that destination is alive (I don't want to follow ICMP  req-resp way)

Configured TTL and flags arguments didn't help to resolve this issue.

```c
const uint32_t ttl = 1000; //ms
rc = sctp_sendmsg(sctp_socket->fd, data.s, data.len, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin), htonl(ppid), 0, 0, ttl, 0);
if (rc < 0) {
    printf("Could not connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `sctp_sendmsg()` returns in case the process receives a signal? Maybe add just register an `alarm()`?

Comment: I didn't check it but seems this way is not suitable for my application because it is single-threaded and in this case the code after sctp_sendmsg will not be executed.

Comment: why? why? Threading has nothing to do here, with alarms. A single threaded - that's even better, no need to worry about mutexes. `the code after sctp_sendmsg will not be executed` why??? If it acts like `select()` or `sleep()` etc. calls, it will just return with ERRNO = EINTR.

Comment: maybe I didn't get your idea? did you propose to send kill -<signal> <pid> to the application?

Comment: Yes, but from inside the application, set an `alarm(1000)`  before entering `sctp_sendmsg`.

Comment: Seems I can re-use it somehow. Thanks a lot for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I think setting SCTP_INIT params will help

```
     struct sctp_initmsg {
     uint16_t sinit_num_ostreams;
     uint16_t sinit_max_instreams;
     uint16_t sinit_max_attempts;
     uint16_t sinit_max_init_timeo;
     };

    sinit_max_attempts:  This integer specifies how many attempts the
      SCTP endpoint should make at resending the INIT.  This value
      overrides the system SCTP 'Max.Init.Retransmits' value.  The
      default value of 0 indicates the use of the endpoint's default
      value.  This is normally set to the system's default
      'Max.Init.Retransmit' value.

   sinit_max_init_timeo:  This value represents the largest timeout or
      retransmission timeout (RTO) value (in milliseconds) to use in
      attempting an INIT.  Normally, the 'RTO.Max' is used to limit the
      doubling of the RTO upon timeout.  For the INIT message, this
      value may override 'RTO.Max'.  This value must not influence
      'RTO.Max' during data transmission and is only used to bound the
      initial setup time.  A default value of 0 indicates the use of the
      endpoint's default value.  This is normally set to the system's
      'RTO.Max' value (60 seconds).
```

Before establishing connection (or call sctp_sendmsg) set socket options like this:

```
    sctp_initmsg init;
    init.sinit_max_attempts   = m_nMaxAttempts;
    init.sinit_max_init_timeo = m_nMaxInitTimeout;

    if (setsockopt(nSockID, SOL_SCTP, SCTP_INITMSG, &init, sizeof(init)) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << strerror(errno);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
```